# Как в телефон без ROOT перенести содержимое data/data/com.@@@.@@@/ с другого телефона?

Tags: apk, android-adb, android

Задавал на [4PDA](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=150358&st=15580) но там мне вря-ли помогут быстро...
У меня есть Samsung Galaxy Ace 2 с ROOT на котором я посредством reverse tethering скачал русский язык для swype. Знаю он хранится наверное в data/data/com.nuance.swype.trial, скопировал сию папку на комп. Есть Samsung Galaxy S 3 Neo без root - на нем нет интернета и скаченный язык русский хотелось бы туда засунуть. Через adb access к папке data/data deinied. Пробовал `run-as ..` - это не debug версия swype.apk а debug-версию не могу найти. Хотел с помощью apktool перебросать в debug изменив `AndroidManifest.xml` но apktool даже без изменений не может разобрать и собрать swype - это его [БАГ](http://4pda.ru/pages/go/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fandroid-apktool%2Fissues%2Fdetail%3Fid%3D550) . Нашёл еще функцию adb backup но она походу всё вместе back-up'ит, Помогите. ***Как с телефона с ROOT в телефон без ROOT перенести содержимое data/data/com.@@@.@@@/  какого либо приложения?***
***PS:*** Я лишь пользователь Android живущий в [стране 3его мира] Узбекистане решающий вечные проблемы с телефоном а не android-developer... 
***UPD:*** На странице с багом apktool сказано вроде бан исправлен но как скачать исправленную версию не сказано.
***Дополнительный вопрос:*** А достаточно ли вообще как я прочёл [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150825/):

> Добавить атрибут
> `android:debuggable="true"` в секцию
> `<application>` файла
> `out/AndroidManifest.xml`

чтобы переделать apk в debug-версию?
***UPD:*** Оказалось не достаточно - с помощью apk studio успешно пересобрал swype.apk с android:debuggable="true" - установил а adb всё равно вякает: `run-as: Package 'com.nuance.swype.trial' is not debuggable` Теперь вопрос `можно ли с помощью adb backup data/data только у одного приложения тронуть а не у всех и как`?

Comment: рутайте второй телефон. Я думаю, для Вас это самый простой способ.

Comment: @KoVadim Да я знаю но телефон на гарантии и там новая какая то тупая защита да и как то "девственности лишать" не охота.

Comment: Неужели нет нормального "белого" способа я ведь не imei поменять хочу а данные приложения!?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, если была бы возможность так легко вытягивать/запихать данные,то никому такая платформа не нужна была бы.

Comment: @KoVadim - что самое обидное [те кому это надо] взломщики всегда смогут сделать на телефоне всё что угодно а обычный кулhацkер :) - нет или с трудом... :( И так везде - от Windows до Nokia 5130,  Android и замков на чемодане для аэропорта

Comment: По-моему НАШЕЛ ИМЕННО ТО ЧТО НАДО. А все говорили "СОВЕРШЕННО НЕЛЬЗЯ" :). [Как перенести игру с рутованного аппарата android 2.3 на НЕрутованный android 4 с помощью Helium ](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=423134&st=540#entry24697903). Сам пока не пробовал. Попробую - отпишусь...